# ¿Como instalar la version de Angular numero 5?

Tags: angular

Como puedo crear un proyecto con urilizando las ultimas versiones de `angular` en este caso la numero 5 (`angular 5`).

Comment: por suerte ahora las últimas versiones vienen alineadas con https://cli.angular.io/ , si creas un proyecto con esta herramienta tendrás un proyecto con las últimas versiones.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas instalar el cli de angular en la versión 1.7

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4
```

Después creas tu proyecto: `ng new nombreProyecto`

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un proyecto con **Angular 5** necesitas los siguiente requerimientos:

> Instalar **Angular CLI 1.5.0** en tu máquina.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

> Crear proyecto Angular.

```
ng new mi-proyecto-angular
```

> Instalar **TypeScript 2.4.2** en tu proyecto.

```
npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0'
```

> Arrancar proyecto Angular en modo desarrollo.

```
ng serve --aot
```

> Distribuir proyecto Angular en modo producción.

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```